# Image from string which is type of Application/Octet-stream

Tags: c#, string, image, base64, converters

I have a base64 string which is provided below. I guess its type is Application/Octet-stream.
I am using code below to convert it to an image. But it gives me error "Paramter is not valid!".

```
string base64string = "AAAAAQEAAAEcEgABHxIAASAS ... F4WQABcFwAAQ==";

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64string)))
{
    pictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}
```

You can get full string from here: http://orion.mn/updateapp/base64_unicode_string.rar

Please, help me how to convert it to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Image.FromStream` method cannot create an Image from your base64 decoded string because it is not a supported file type.

> Managed GDI+ has built-in encoders and decoders that support the following file types: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF ...
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

After decoding your base64 string, it appears it's a CWD file type. Ensure that your base64 encoded string is a BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, or TIFF file and it should work.

Comment: thanks for advice. But, please explain "CWD file type". And, is it possible to know the base64 string is which one of BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, or TIFF?